# Want to get checkpoint details for particular VM through "VMM PowerShell Script" activity

Tags: powershell, system-center, scvmm

i have orchestrator with service manager installed . now i want to give facility to my developers to get checkpoint information about respective VMs (particular) from SMportal so that they can revert to specific  checkpoint if they want.

below powershell script is giving me checkpoint info for entire environment -

$vmcheck = Get-VM | where { $_.LastRestoredVMCheckpoint -like "* *" }
[string]$body = "`n"
$body += "<tr><td></td><td>CheckPoint</td><td>Location</td></tr>`n"
foreach ($vm in $vmcheck) {
$body += ("{0}{1}{2}`n" -f ($vm.name, $vm.LastRestoredVMCheckPoint, $vm.CheckPointLocation))
}
$body += "</table>`n"
can i use above script for my particular VM ?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your command `Get-VM` gets a collection of all VMs on the current server. To limit that to one VM, just specify a name

```
Get-VM -name "theVMName" | where...
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: its working thanks a lot ...i am following below article  - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25186.orchestrator-check-system-center-vm-snapshots.aspx

to achieve this task , can you help me here that how can i specify  email template ?

Comment: I never used System Center in my life, but this is just PowerShell. If the answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: i will do it later because my reputation is only 11